# What could be causing this [object HTMLTableCellElement] tooltip on Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

On Firefox, when hovering the mouse over a certain table in my webpage a strange `[object HTMLTableCellElement]` tooltip appears:

[image: Strange tooltip]

**What needs to happen for this to occur?** I am having a hard time narrowing what part of my code is the culprit because I don't even know what to look for.

---

Edit, solved the problem:

This table belongs to a Dojo Dijit [template](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/_Templated.html). I accidentaly gave one of the template's nodes the `dojo-attach-point` "title", causing Dojo to, during the rendering of the Widget, do a

```
this.title = the_node_with_the_bad_attach_point
```

The node is then converted to a string and that is where the "[object HTMLTableElement]" comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably this:

```
cell.title = cell;
```

which can be described as a failed attempt to store the reference to the cell inside its own title property (which holds the string that is shown inside the tooltip on mouse-over).

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/VwYRP/

Object references - when coerced to strings - usually look like so: `'[object Constructor]'`, where `Constructor` is the constructor function which the browser uses to instantiate that object.

Answer (score 2):

Install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and inspect the element. Do you see a `title` in the text? Check the DOM attributes. Maybe you can spot it there? Or maybe some JavaScript does not work properly. You'll get that message if you do an `alert(document.createElement('th'));`.